# a regular expression with except word doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex, except

I have the code

```js
let dirtyHtml = `<img class="emojione" src="">
<img class="a" src="edw">
<img class="emojione" src="" />
<img class="emojione" src=""/>

<img src="">`;

let clearHtml = dirtyHtml.replace(/<img[^<>]+(?!emojione)[^<>]+>/gi, '');

console.log(clearHtml);
```

I expect to see this

```
<img class="emojione" src="">
<img class="emojione" src="" />
<img class="emojione" src=""/>
```

But I'll see empty string...

What wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: are you kidding me? )))

Comment: This will do a better job: `clearHtml = dirtyHtml.replace(/<img(?:(?!emojione)[^<>])*>/gi, '');` - but listen to others when they say parsing HTML with regex is not the best solution!

Comment: @ridgerunner which the way for a better solution do I have to choose? Use DOM interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/<img(?:(?!emojione).)*>/gi` will match anything between `<img` and `>` that doesn't contain the string `emojione`. Like this:

```js
let dirtyHtml = `<img class="emojione" src="">
<img class="a" src="edw">
<img class="emojione" src="" />
<img class="emojione" src=""/>

<img src="">`;

let clearHtml = dirtyHtml.replace(/<img(?:(?!emojione).)*>/gi, '');

console.log(clearHtml);
```

Comment: nice! what if I want match anything between <img and > that DOES contain the string emojione?

Comment: sry got it  /<img.*(?:emojione).*>/gi

Comment: @rick use this `/<img[^>]*(?:emojione)[^>]*>/gi`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (doesn't matter `img` whether `[a-z]{3}` because `src`'s supported elements have **more** than 3 chars http://www.w3resource.com/html/attributes/html-src-attribute.php but it's easier to write `img`)

```js
let dirtyHtml = `<img class="emojione" src="">
<img class="a" src="edw">
<img class="emojione" src="" />
<img class="emojione" src=""/>

<img src="">`;

let clearHtml = dirtyHtml.replace(/(<img class="[a-z]?" src="[a-z]+">)|(<img src="">)/gi, '');

console.log(clearHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't repeat many [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/4454454) why RegExp usage to modify HTML is a bad idea (and by many considered as a hack), but I would like to show how natural it could be to use **[jQuery](https://api.jquery.com)** for this task

```js
let dirtyHtml = `<img class="emojione" src="">
<img class="a" src="edw">
<img class="emojione" src="" />
<img class="emojione" src=""/>

<img src="">`;

// Put your html string within some HTML element to make a starting point
var $wrap = $('<div/>').append(dirtyHtml);
// Remove image tags without specific class
$wrap.find('img:not(.emojione)').remove();

console.log($wrap.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please, repeat this solution without jQuery

Comment: I was asking for this: `const dirtyDom = document.createElement('div'); dirtyDom.innerHTML = '<img class="emojione" src=""><img class="a" src="edw"><img class="emojione" src="" /><img class="emojione" src=""/><img src="">'; dirtyDom.querySelectorAll('img:not(.emojione)').forEach(node => dirtyDom.removeChild(node));`. Thanks :)